# Test Error Comparing Props and Data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-test-utils

I have a component that when `created()` sets `date:` with `null` or with `props.datainicial`.

```
export default {
  props: ['numeroDaParcela', 'datainicial'],
  data () {
    return {
      date: null,
      dateBR: '',
      modal: false
    }
  },
  created () {
    if (this.datainicial === '' ||
      this.datainicial === undefined) {
        this.date = null
    } else {
      this.date = this.datainicial
    }
  }
```

In DevTools with no `props`:

[image]

In DevTools with some `props`:

[image]

When I do my test:

```
import { mount } from 'vue-test-utils'
import SelecionadorData from '@/components/Shared/SelecionadorData.vue'

describe('SelecionadorData.vue', () => {

  it('should receive the props datainicial', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(SelecionadorData)
    wrapper.setProps({
      datainicial: '2018-01-01'
    })
    expect(wrapper.vm.date).toBe('2018-01-01')
  })
})
```

I get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`created` only runs 1 time when component is created. 
When you use `setProps`, component props will be updated but `created` method will not be called again.

```
import { mount } from 'vue-test-utils'
import SelecionadorData from '@/components/Shared/SelecionadorData.vue'

describe('SelecionadorData.vue', () => {

  it('should receive the props datainicial', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(SelecionadorData,
    {
        propsData: {
          datainicial: '2018-01-01'
        }
    })
    expect(wrapper.vm.date).toBe('2018-01-01')
  })
})
```